# call multiple functions from single event with unobtrusive javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, unobtrusive-javascript

I have an input element

```
<select id="test"></select>
```

on change I want to call multiple functions

```
$('#test').change(function1, function2);
```

functions for now are just alerts for now

```
var function1 = function(){alert('a');};
var function2 = function(){alert('b');};
```

Only the second function is being called. I know this because of alerts and brake points. I know one way to correct this would be to call function1, and function2 from another function, but I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prefer not to use anonymous functions so I would create a new function and place all work inside it.

```
$('#test').change(onSelectChange);

var onSelectChange = function() {
    function1();
    function2();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can always chain them:

```
$('#test').change(function1).change(function2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

```
$('#test').change(function1);
$('#test').change(function2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#test').change(function(){function1(); function2();});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something like:

```
$('#test').change(function(){
   function1();
   function2();
};
```